# Can there be a single word clause?

Tags: verbs, clauses, sentence-fragments, is-it-a-rule, is-it-a-sentence

It's said that a sentence must always contain a subject and a verb but I have read somewhere that the word "No" itself is a complete sentence. How?
Also a sentence always has at least one clause and clauses are s+v combo, So how "No" acts as both sentence and a clause?

Comment: Perhaps in a similar way to your own single-word sentence, "How?".

Comment: @Lawrence What?

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. Indeed.

Comment: @Lawrence [Autological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word)......

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

> *Go.*
>
> *Eat.*
>
> *Leave.*

Insert any other intransitive verb used in the [imperative mood](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/the-imperative).

An imperative construction is considered complete (complete sentence, independent clause), even though you can't see a subject in it.

Have a talk with your grammarian or linguist regarding the classification of [pro-forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-sentence) (such as *No.*) and [elliptical constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

Answer (score 0):

You can consider it as an abbreviation. When you say No/Yes it may refer to a sentence such as "Yes, it is," or "No, it isn't"

Answer (score 0):

There are many "One word sentences"

- Interrogative - Who? How? When?
- Imperative - Stop! Halt! Jump!
- Declarative - Me. Him. Her
- Locative - Here. There. Everywhere.
- Nominative - Jane. John. Harry.

And so on. In these cases, the subject and the verb are tied to the context of the situation and are implied.

For instance,

- A asks - "Where is your father?"
- B answers - "Inside"

Here the subject and verb are implied.

In short, I think a single word sentence is not grammatically wrong unless it is devoid of context which supplies the verb and the subject.

Comment: I think nominative and declarative are same. What you mention as declarative is objective, or accusative. It looks like a mix up of sentence types and cases.  Sentences are a) Declarative/ assertive/ statements, b) Interrogative, c) Imperative, and d) Exclamatory.  Cases are: a) Nominative, b) accusative, c) dative, d) genitive, and e) vocative.  You may check it.  I may be corrected if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is an important part of speech that some people forget about, called Interjections. I believe "yes" or "no" could be considered an interjection when used alone. Yes/no are not nouns, pronouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, prepositions, or conjunctions when used in this context.

Comment: No, interjections are spontaneous expressions of emotions and do not include "yes" or "no" apart from single cases in which they might index joy or disappointment respectively.